# Jest Mock import in tested file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to mock import to my DAO functions from controller file. Want to test controller's methods without accessing database. So, now in `users.contoller.js` I have following code:

```
import * as usersDAO from '../db/users.dao'

export function registerUser(user) {
    if (user.name === '1') return true;
    return false;
}
```

Current implementation was made just for test purposes. But the main problem is that in users.dao I'm trying to connect to database and test fails.

My current test implementation looks following:

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
jest.mock('../../db/users.dao')

import { registerUser } from '../../controllers/users.controller'

test('should register new user', () => {
    expect(registerUser({})).toBeFalsy();
})
```

Is it possible to mock my import, so that I'll be able to use some mock implementation of DAO instead of working with real database?